# Como aumentar o tamanho do modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um modal que é alimentado dinamicamente pela BD e gostava de conseguir aumentar a largura dele no entanto o máximo que consigo encontrar é adicionar a class modal-lg mas eu preciso de uma largura maior, o que posso fazer para resolver este problema?

Este é o código que está a definir a largura do modal:

```
<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered' role='document'>
```

Comment: Já tentou definir no seu CSS o `width` que deseja?

Comment: Se não for o que quer me fala, ou se tiver alguma dúvida comenta lá.

Comment: É mesmo o que precisava Hugo, obrigado!